# How to pass information into new Thread(..);

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I playing a sound file, and I create a new thread every time the playSoundFile() method is called. I just need to know how to pass the information from the method call into run() within the thread, so It can be used within.

```
        public void playSoundFile(File file) {//http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/java-l/sound-in-an-application-90681
            new Thread(
                    new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            try {
    //get an AudioInputStream
    //this input stream can't use the file passed to playSoundFile()
                                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                                ...
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();

        }
```

Comment: You IDE should suggest `file` be made final and correct it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply declare the variable to be `final`, then you can use it in your anonymous inner class:

```
public void playSoundFile(final File file) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void playSoundFile(final File file)
```

Problem solved. Inner classes can only access final variables of the parent function.

If you have a lot of information, subclass `Thread` or `Runnable` and add member variables.

EDIT: What's the point of the `new Runnable` in your example? `Thread` already implements `Runnable`.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous inner classes (like the `Runnable` you're creating here) can reference `final` local variables from their enclosing scope.  If you want access to the `file` parameter, change the function to make it `final`:

```
public void playSoundFile(final File file) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Now, your new `Runnable` can reference this variable without problems.